# Python - boolean matter

Tags: python

Argument is :

> Given 2 strings, change them to lower case and check if one of them is
>   at the end of the other

My answer is :

```
a="xyz"
b="12xyz"
a = a.lower()
b = b.lower()
c=max(a,b)
d=min(a,b)
e=len(d)
if d==c[-e:]:
 print True
else:
 print False
```

It should return `True` . But it returns `False` . When I give this value :

```
a="ambala12xyz"
b="12xyz"
```

it returns `True` . What is the problem here ?

Comment: check the values of c and d

Comment: `max` and `min` do not compare the strings based on the length (which seems to be the premise your approach builds upon), but on their sort order. E.g. `max('abc', 'c')` returns `c`.

Comment: @FelixKling: actually, in python you _can_ use `max/min` to compare by the length: `x=max(a, b, key=len)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the shortest and the most intuitive way is:

```
a = a.lower()
b = b.lower()
print a.endswith(b) or b.endswith(a)
```

Or if you want to use max, min functions:

```
a = a.lower()
b = b.lower()
c = max(a, b, key=len)
d = min(a, b, key=len)
print d == c[-len(d):]
```

But in my opinion it's not so explicit way as with `endswith` function. Also this function does not work correctly with strings of same length.

Comment: right, it is not working on same length.so need to add more one line.

Answer (score 2):

you should use `endswith`

```
In [13]: a="ambala12xyz"

In [14]: b="12xyz"

In [15]: b.endswith(a)
Out[15]: False

In [16]: a="xyz"

In [17]: b="12xyz"

In [18]: b.endswith(a)
Out[18]: True
```

Comment: without this i can do full process with `if/else` . but what is the problem in my mentioned code ?

Comment: You can do `if b.endswith(a)` as well. It's the `max` and `min` causing the error btw.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing characters, you need to compare the strings by length:

```
a="xyz"
b="12xyz"
a = a.lower()
b = b.lower()
if len(a) > len(b):
  c, d = a, b
else:
  c, d = b, a
e=len(d)
# print d==c[-e:]
# or:
if d==c[-e:]:
 print True
else:
 print False
```

Comment: what is the return result of `max()/min()` ? shortest ?

Comment: @slash-bang: As I indicated in my comment, `max` and `min` sort the elements by their natural order (for strings it is their alphabetical order) and they then return the last or first element of the sorted list.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea:

print (a.lower().endswith(b.lower()) or b.lower().endswith(a.lower()))

Comment: without this i know one more way. but is the problem here ?

Comment: no - as mentioned elsewhere, the problem is that `c = min(a, b)` does not make `c` equal the shortest string

Comment: why ? `min()` function return the shortest string. isn't it ? and i just saved it into a variables `c` .

Comment: @sje397 Why you execute .lower() method 4 times when you can execute it twice? It slows program...

Comment: @Denis Nikanorov Just meant to be illustrative

Comment: ow ! that means for `max` if i give `a="wxy"` and `b="z"`  then it will show `b` is biggest ? right ?

Comment: @slash-bang Sorry I was wrong - as others have mentioned `min(a, b)` will return the string that comes first alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at your variables you will quickly see what's going wrong:

```
a: xyz
b: 12xyz
c: xyz
d: 12xyz
e: 5
c[-e]: xyz
```

Then it's pretty clear that d != c[-e:] (12xyz != xyz).

What you're doing wrong is that you're assuming that

```
min("abc", "defgh")
```

will return 3, but when doing max() and min() on strings you're comparing which string is "higher" or "lower", so that will actually return "abc".

Comment: i checked the min and max first. so e will be 3 . and it will check last 3 characters of max with min.

Comment: Actually, when you do a "max()" on a a string it will return the "highest" string, not the biggest character count. So max("xyz", "12xyz") will not return 5 but "xyz" (since "xyz" comes alphabetically after "12xyz"). That's what I meant when I said you should print your variables.